# Android aidl cant import

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

I have an aidl file:

```
package com.xyz;

interface ICallback 
{
void CallbackMsg(String type, String value1);
}
```

I have another aidl file:

```
package com.xyz;

import com.xyz.ICallback;

interface ISendMsg 
{
int getPid();
void SendMsg(String value1);
void registerCallBack(ICallback cb);
void unregisterCallBack(ICallback cb);
}
```

It gives error as: couldn't find import for class com.xyz.ICallback

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How can you set a parameter which is interface to another interface method??? That's why you getting error.

Comment: Even if I remove those 2 two methods(registerCallback and unregisterCallBack), I still get error on import statement. So I guess, its not related to interface object being passed as parameter

Comment: Why you `imprt com.xyz.Icalback` when you remove both `statemnets`. You have to remove that import line also???

Comment: I removed those 2 statements, just to check if they were causing error as you suggested in your 1st comment. 
I need those 2 statements

Comment: What you can do is extend the interface with another interface [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921412/why-interface-can-not-implement-another-interface) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was copy pasting aidl files from other source and thats why it created a problem.
Once I created the aidl files in the project itself, it stopped giving errors?