# OOP interface inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

My question is that can one interface extend another interface or it implements another interface.

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
}

OR 

interface B implements A {
}
```

Comment: Have you *tried* compiling that code?

Comment: Yes, an interface can extend another interface in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why interface can not implement another interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921412/why-interface-can-not-implement-another-interface)

Comment: Please show the code post compilation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In terms of Inheritance in case of "INTERFACE" they always extends they never implement anything.

Answer (score 0):

Barring Java 8 extensions, an `interface` doesn't implement anything.

So therefore `extends` is the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

An interface can only extend another interface, since an interface cannot contain any implementation.

```
interface ParentInterface{
    void myMethod();
}

interface SubInterface extends ParentInterface{
    void anotherMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can via the `extends` keyword, as interfaces can't implement any methods, only declare their signatures.

```
interface A {
    public void foo();
}

interface B extends A {
    // You don't implement the methods from A here
    public void bar();
}

class C implements B {
    public void foo(){
    }
    public void bar(){
    }
}
```

Any class that then implements `B` must then implement the methods from `A` as well.

Comment: Sam he is asking about interface a class can always implement but he is asking in terms of interface.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh Yes, and I explained about interfaces

Comment: Ok... Actually you was implementing it in class so just pointed out.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh Whether or not I gave an example of a class is beside the point, I still explained the relevant details about interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an interface can **extend** another interface in Java.

```
// this interface extends from the Body interface:
public interface FourLegs extends Body
{
  public void walkWithFourLegs( );

}
```

Well but we must think,

> *When would we want an interface to extend another interface*

We know that any class that implements an interface must implement the method headings that are declared in that interface. And, if that interface extends from other interfaces, then the *implementing class must also implement the methods in the interfaces that are being extended or derived from*.

So, in the example above, if we have a class that implements the FourLegs interface, then that class must have definitions for any method headings in both the FourLegs interface and the Body interface.

> *Question part 2:Interface do not Implement another interface,Because*

Implements denotes defining an implementation for the methods of an interface. However interfaces have no implementation so that's not possible.