# Interface implementing another interface in android developer reference docs

Tags: java, android

May be I am missing some understanding or may be I am unable to understand some "wording" (I am fairly new to JAVA and android), but if you look at the developer reference docs for android, then one can find that an *interface is "**implementing**" another interface*. For example, among others, look at [ComponentCallbacks2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html) & [SurfaceHolder.Callback2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback2.html). But, as per an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921412/why-an-interface-can-not-implement-another-interface), an *interface **cannot implement another** interface, it can **only extend** one*. ***So, what is going on in the android reference docs?*** Shouldn't the keyword "extends" be used in the android reference docs, instead of "implements" when it comes to relationships between interfaces?

Also, say an interface `interfaceB` implements another interface `interfaceA` and a class, say `ClassXYZ`, implements `interfaceB`. While declaring the class in the reference docs, sometimes it is mentioned as:

```
public class ClassXYZ implements interfaceB
```

(for example, in the [declaration of Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), it is mentioned that `Activity class implements ComponentCallbacks2`, *but it **is not*** mentioned that Activity implements ComponentCallbacks even if ComponentCallbacks2 "implements" ComponentCallbacks2)

and sometimes as

```
public class ClassXYZ implements interfaceB, interfaceA
```

(for example, in the [declaration of AlteredCharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/AlteredCharSequence), it is mentioned that AlteredCharSequence class implements CharacterSequence, *and it **is*** mentioned that AlteredCharSequence implements GetChars even if [GetChars "implements" CharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/GetChars.html))

What is the difference between the two declarations? How does the class inheritance diagram look in both the cases?

Comment: I think the android docs are simply using the wrong terminology. `ComponentCallbacks2` __extends__ `ComponentCallbacks`. Interfaces are not implementations. See [some source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.java).

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, can you answer the second part of the question? (The one that starts with "Also say")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the android docs are simply using the wrong terminology. `ComponentCallbacks2` **extends** `ComponentCallbacks`. Interfaces are not implementations. See [some source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.java).

As for the rest, if interface `B` extends interface `A`, then any implementation of `B` is also an implementation of `A`, even if the documentation fails to describe it as such. So any class that implements `ComponentCallbacks2` does implement `ComponentCallbacks`, whether the docs mention it or not.

Comment: Yes, but should the parent interface be mentioned in the class declaration of the class that implements B?

Comment: There is no need to mention it in the class declaration. It also does no harm to mention it, if it helps readers understand the purpose of the class.

Comment: So, say a Class C implements B (which extends A). Then are both the following are correct?:

1) class C implements B
2) class C implements B, A